# Cancel/Abort Axios Post on Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have got a Vue Component which has a list of values, when you select these values this changed the selected array, which in tern is posted to an endpoint.

I have an issue if the user spam clicks these values, as an individual post is created for each change, I want it so that if the user selects another item then the currently pending post is cancelled, so then the new value is posted and updates the endpoint with both the selected items.

However i'm having an issue with aborting the current axios request, I have provided the code below. There are no errors, the request simply doesn't cancel.

```
export default {
    props: {
        endpoint: {
            default: '',
            type: String
        },
        parameters: {
            default: null,
            type: Object
        }
    },
    data: () => ({
        loaded: false,
        selected: [],
        save: [],
        data: [],
        cancel: undefined
    }),
    methods: {
        update() {

            const self = this;

            let params = this.parameters;
            params.data = this.selected;

            this.$root.$emit('saving', {
                id: this._uid,
                saving: true
            });

            if (self.cancel !== undefined) {
                console.log('cancel');
                this.cancel();
            }

            window.axios.post(this.endpoint + '/save', params, {
                cancelToken: new window.axios.CancelToken(function executor(c) {
                    self.cancel = c;
                })
            }).then(() => {
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.loaded = true;
                    this.$root.$emit('saving', {
                        id: this._uid,
                        saving: false
                    });
                });
            }).catch(function (thrown) {
                if (window.axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
                    console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I have got a global instance of Axios created on my Vue Application.